# Find unique Arraylist in an ArrayList of ArrayLists

Tags: java, arraylist

As I understand ArrayList class inherit equals() function of its parent 'List' class to find if two member objects are same. Does that mean that 'contains()' linear search(using 'equal') for a duplicate entry in the ArrayList? So the complexity of the 'contains' is O(n)?

If I am using ArrayList of Arraylist then the complexity of contains function will be O(n*m)? If yes, then is there any replacement of contains function which can get some hash(Based on contents) of the member ArrayList and confirm that two ArrayList objects are equal?

Edit: I am just trying to find number of unique elements in an ArrayList of ArrayList. Like {{0,0,3},{1,2,3},{0,0,3}} should give {{0,0,3},{1,2,3}}.

Comment: Your understanding is correct. You would have to write the replacement method and hash function yourself.

Comment: You can get logarithmic performance if you sort your List(s) and then use a binary search. But the normal contains method is linear.

Comment: There are better suited data structures for `contains` such as a `HashSet` but would need more details on what you are trying to do (as there are down-sides as well). Sets by definition do not contain duplicates.

Comment: Question Edited. So that means I have to create my own function? Will hash function of HashSet create hash based on contents or on the reference value of the Object?

Comment: @Mangat Rai: HashSet works with hashCode/equals, not just with references.

Comment: I assume that Hashing of an ArrayList will take O(m) time, that means uniqueness can be found in O(n*m). which would take O(n*m^2).
can anyone please answer it so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have an `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>` you can pass it to `HashSet<ArrayList<Integer>>`'s constructor and have a unique set of `ArrayLists`

```
List<ArrayList<Integer>> mylist_list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(); 
ArrayList<Integer> mylist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
...
for(ArrayList<Integer> list : mylist_list)
{
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list.toArray()));
}
Set<ArrayList<Integer>> mylist_set = new HashSet<ArrayList<Integer>>(mylist_list);

for(ArrayList<Integer> list : mylist_set)
{
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list.toArray()));            
}
```

Yielded output of

```
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 2]
```

When passing duplicates to the `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>`

Comment: I was going to ask you to answer it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem! Of course, you want to construct a HashSet to begin with if you only need uniques :)

Comment: @C.B. Can you pls answer above question by Alex?

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question. I was thinking of calling `equals` to compare two `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>`s, and forgot the context of `contains`.

Answer (score 0):

Complexity is O(N).
Implementation next :

```
 public int indexOf(Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            if (elementData[i]==null)
                return i;
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            if (o.equals(elementData[i]))
                return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

yes, `contains` calls `indexOf` method.